# Woocommerce add to cart and login button not working, quantity button missing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing annoying issues with woocommerce.

First, nothing happens anymore when I click on my 'Add to card' button from the content-single-product page. The button becomes disabled but the product isn't added to cart (even if I can see its id in hidden input).

I tried to update both WP and WC versions but it didn't change anything. <strike>Even worse, my quantity buttons disappeared</strike>. I'm working on my own theme and I don't use WC's CSS but it used to work before. The JS scripts are loading properly and I got no errors in the console.

I think cookies aren't the problem because I can add products to cart from the home page with a custom script.

I even tried to switch from my custom file to the original one but it still doesn't work.

Last point, my login button isn't triggering any action anymore.

I really don't know what could be the issue(s)... Any help will be really appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
It seems that my problem isn't coming from my custom WC files. Even if I delete my folder, the bugs are still here. However, if I switch to WP default theme, it works.

**EDIT 2:**
It really looks like a JS problem. Even if my scripts are loaded, it seems that 'add-to-cart' isn't triggered.

**EDIT 3:**
I fixed my issue with quantity buttons, it was due to WP update. They now make quantity buttons a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can help by any chance...

My problem came from my angular module declaration. For some reason, it made my WC process crash silently.

More details on [github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/8094#issuecomment-98609453).